# How to load more web page content using java

Tags: java, android, jquery, html, web

I fetched data from a webpage(http://dongxi.douban.com/), when you visit this webpage you will find that when the page reach the bottom it will start to load more,I searched and found that this effect is implements by jquery.
I want to use this page as a resource of my Android projects,and I just simple fetch the limited data.I need more data,how can I write java code to auto load more webpage content just like when we browse this and reach the bottom?

Comment: You can trace request from this page using. Modern browsers have developer console with logs of request. Or you can reverse engineer javascript from site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to find the service that is providing the data for the web and use it for your app.

Check the following service: `http://dongxi.douban.com/j/feed/` and the parameters with the console.

[image]

Comment: But they don't provide one.

Comment: Use, for example, the chrome console in order to see the requests.

Comment: So then just put those headers and send a request?

Comment: It's totally doable,isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the parameter you need to send is `until_id=1686961444` but you will have to find how it determinates the number of the `until_id`. The services is exposed.

Comment: Alright,I'll try.It's really nice to have your answer here.

Comment: hey,man,I just searched "until_id=" in the html code and found a url like this "http://dongxi.douban.com/?until_id=1806198404&amp;subscribe_only=0",all the data I need is just in here and there is no need to put headers or something,I can just find this url recursively and get endless data.Thank you so much!!!